# Multiple row selection on click

Tags: java, swing, onclick, jtable, row

I was wondering if the following case is possible with jtable:

R4 and R6 are "sub rows" and they reference R1, so whenever I click on R1, it should auto-select R4 and R6.

[image]

Comment: Yes it's possible, but would require some juggling and side stepping of some events under certain conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. This is a very basic 'hacky' example which should give you enough information about the method calls involved. This will select row 3 & 5 whenever you select row 1:

```
// jt is a JTable defined at class level for handle visibility
jt = new JTable() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        super.valueChanged(e);
        if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()) return;

        if(jt.getSelectedRow() == 1 && jt.getSelectedRows().length == 1) {
            ListSelectionModel lsm = jt.getSelectionModel();
            lsm.addSelectionInterval(3, 3);
            lsm.addSelectionInterval(5, 5);
        }
    }
};
```